# Cant get a math.random to work in two different places

Tags: math, lua

```lua
function INV:DeleteInventoryItem( ply, pos, item)
    local rarity = INV.PLAYERS[ply:SteamID64()][pos].quality
    ---print(rarity)
    local value = "credits"
    if(rarity == "Common")then
        local amount = math.floor(math.random(1, 30))
        table.remove( INV.PLAYERS[ply:SteamID64()], pos)
        local var = ply:ChatPrint("You got ".. amount .." credits from deconstructing!")
        ply:INVAddCredits( amount )
        self.SAVE:SendInventory( ply )
        local updatevalue = INV.PLAYERS[ply:SteamID64()].inventorydata.credits
        UpdateDatabase(value, ply:SteamID(), updatevalue)
    end
end
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the same value from the `amount` variable, so it says that you got a certain amount when it actually gave you a different amount.

I am really confused on how I can make it the same amount... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have a question for clarification: Are you saying that the `amount` being added to the string in the `var` variable is different from the amount passed to `ply:INVAddCredits` or are you saying that you're calling `math.random()` again somewhere else and it's giving you a different result?

Comment: Is it worth investigating what happens inside ply:INVAddCredits, to see if the value 'amount' is being interpreted differently once passed to the function?   By the way, I noticed you use ply:SteamID64 most times but omit the '64' on the last line.

Comment: @Allister i'm saying that, the amount being added to the string in the var is different to the amount passed to ply:INVAddCredits

Comment: Then I would follow @dahk 's suggestion and post the code from ply:INVAddCredits to see if amount is being manipulated at all.

Comment: Put this immediately after the second amount line:
  
  `print (INV.PLAYERS[ply:SteamID64()].inventorydata.credits);`

This will narrow down if it is actually INVAddCredits that is wrong, or something to do with later saving the inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help you guys have been, I since have fixed the issue and it was something wrong with the adding of the inventory credits.

-Thanks D12